# My NMM unwarrantedly changed to GOG

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nexus-mod-manager

I went into NMM, to Skyrim Special Edition, to download a mod for it.
To my surprise, I was no longer able to, and got the message saying "*Nexus Mod Manager is not set up to work for Skyrim Special Edition GOG*" (see the image below).
Then I looked at my NMM and noticed at the bottom that it changed to GOG.
I did not change my NMM to GOG.

How do I change it back to regular NMM?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: NMM is no longer supported. In the long run, you are likely better off switching to Vortex or Mod Organizer 2. If you still want to use NMM anyway, have you tried using the Change Game toolbar item, as the error message suggests? What happens when you do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "change game?"

Comment: It is presumably talking about one of the buttons in the toolbar, probably the one with the name of the game. Unfortunately, nobody uses NMM anymore, so I'm basically just reading the error message and guessing.

Comment: I think Kevin was referring to the error message saying "change with left bar's bottom button" . Have you tried that?

Comment: I figured that was the key but wasn't sure how to do that or what exactly it meant by " left bar's button."
What left bar's button is it talking about?

Comment: On the left side there is a vertical bar with several icons. I think you can mouseover to see the description, and one will probably let you change the mode.

Comment: "On the left side, there is a vertical bar???"
There are bars all over the place.
On the left side of what?
And what is the description of this vertical bar?

Comment: Okay, I posted new images.
I understand what the bar is and I see that GOG crap.
The red arrow is pointing at it.
However, I don't know what is meant by "click the left bottom button."

Comment: As Kevin stated, NMM is bunk, and since I see you're on Windows 11, I'd expect even more instability, as NMM has likely never been touched up to fully integrate with whatever weirdness Windows 11 introduces.

Comment: Just tell me what is this "Left Bar's Bottom Button" so I can get rid of this thing.
I wanna keep the mods I have and I don't want to start a new game

Comment: One of your screenshots has it already. It is *literally* the left bar, bottom button, that when highlighted, in your very screenshot, says "Skyrim SE current download mode: Skyrim GOG Game Mode". I assume clicking that will let you do something, since somewhere else tells you to CLICK that button. You've answered your own question, rather rudely. Otherwise, you will just want to re-scan games with NMM, and see if it correctly finds your non-GOG version, again, as your screenshot indicates.

Comment: WOW!
It didn't sound that obvious as it is.
Nevertheless, I did click that button and nothing happened.
I even rescanned and tried to download a mod from SE and the download button isn't activating.
What makes you think I was being "rude?"
I just want that crap gone!